# Dynamically rendering Custom Radio Button Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to dynamically render a custom button component in a form in react js.

Here is my radio custom button component.

```
export class CustomRadio extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormGroup>
          <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel>
          <br />

          <input type="radio" name={this.props.name} />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The below is how I call that component in a form

```
 <CustomRadio label="status" />
```

Anyways I was not able to get the expected output. Can anyone help me out to solve this matter?

Comment: can you paste in the rendered html? A codesandbox would help a lot.

Comment: @VishalSharma I added the html output

Comment: I was asking for HTML text and not the rendered HTML. I meant rendered HTML from your react code. Sorry for the confusion .

Comment: @VishalSharma 

<CustomRadio label="status" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you must import your component as,

```
import {CustomRadio} from './CustomRadio';  //because you are exporting as named export
```

Another thing, as you are using `this.props.name` you must pass it as,

```
<CustomRadio label="Status" name="name"/>
```

By looking at `FormGroup`, I think you are using [`reactstrap`](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/), in `reactstrap` you can use this to get `radio` button,

```
<FormGroup>
  <Label>
     <input type="radio" name={this.props.name} />
     {this.props.label}
  </Label>
</FormGroup>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-53ctdw)

---

**Note:**

If `ControlLabel` is another custom component, then you can do this,

```
<FormGroup>
  <ControlLabel>
     <input type="radio" name={this.props.name} />
     {this.props.label}
  </ControlLabel>
</FormGroup>
```

And your `ControlLabel` component should be,

```
const ControlLabel = (props) => {
   return (
      <Label>{props.children}</Label>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to render two radio buttons under the same label. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @Ruks I suggest you, don't do that rather have separate `<Label><Input/></Label>` combination for second radio button.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned the name as a prop in CustomRadio component you must need to pass name also from here as follows:

```
<CustomRadio label="status" name="Xyz" />
```